# Convert json string to modified RDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In table, there are three columns: name, age and details. Ex-

|name|age|details|
|A|12|"{\"address\": \"add-1\", \"pincode\":110011}"|
|B|35|"{\"address\": \"add-2\",\"state\": \"ny\", \"pincode\":112121}"|
|C|36|"{\"address\": \"add-2\",\"state\": \"ohio\", \"city\":\"athens\"}"|

The table contain million of records with "details" column as serialized json string. The nature of "details" column is dynamic in nature with respect to any key can be there, say new columns, nested json.

I would like to create Java RDD / DataFrame with fields in nested json as first class variables, such that df.printSchema() shows as,

|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- age: long (nullable = true)
|-- address: string (nullable = true)
|-- state: string (nullable = true)
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- pincode: long (nullable = true)
|-- {new dynamic key}: string (nullable = true)

This schema will make aggregation easily.

I wrote following code but not able to do get above required schema,

```
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("select name, age, details");
    JavaRDD modifiedRDD = df.toJavaRDD().map((Function) row -> {
     Row modifiedRow = null;
     if (row != null) {
        String details = row.getString(2);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
           UserInfo userInfo = mapper.readValue(details, UserInfo.class);
           Map details = userInfo.getDetails();

           // TODO create modified RDD using default columns and exploded details map such that keys in map are first level columns i.e. userInfo and keys from details map
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     return modifiedRow;
    });
```

Objective is to convert from the raw RDD to modified RDD, persist in HDFS, and then do computation so that multiple aggregations can be performed on same set of modified RDD.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is the json file in this format ?
{"name":"A","age":12,"details":{"address":"add1","pincode":110111}}
{"name":"B","age":35,"details":{"address":"add2","state":"NY","pincode":111111}}
{"name":"C","age":36,"details":{"address":"add3","state":"ohio","city":"athens"}}

Comment: Actually I am reading from table and details column is escaped json string.

Comment: @Himaprasoon - If it is in the format like you mentioned, can we get the desired DF schema?

Comment: Just to be clear - in the code snippet you write _// Please note that keys in the map may not be pre known._, and at the same time you list a specific schema you want the json-sting to be converted to. Do you mean that the keys are known, but some keys may be missing from the json-string?

Comment: Yes that also need to be taken care. What I wanted to say that if I traverse million of records, then only would have exhaustive list of keys from json string. I want to support dataframe schema for all keys in json string.

(Removed that line to avoid confusion)